# Sap ui5 : why attachEvent method doesnt work with "mouseenter" event?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, eventhandler, mouseenter

I'm trying to add mouseenter handler to one of the control (PlanningCalendarAppointment).
Thats what i have tried already.

```js
control.attachEvent("mouseenter", function () {
       console.log("test"); // Fixed compilation error
});
```

but it doesnt give any effects.

Comment: if this worked you may want to set this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try .[attachBrowserEvent](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control/methods/attachBrowserEvent) instead of attachEvent:

```
control.attachBrowserEvent("mouseenter", function () {
       console.log("test"); // Fixed compilation error
});
```